# Difference between equality and isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't really understand the difference between sets being equal and isomorphic.  I know that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal of $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.  I know two sets are isomorphic is there is a homomorphic bijection between the two sets, i.e., they have the same cardinality and the elements of each can be identified in such a way that they behave in exactly the same way.  (In other words, the two sets have the same structure.)

Is equality stronger?  I guess my main question is:

**If two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal, does this imply they are isomorphic?  How do $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, which are purely set theoretic statements, imply that the *structure* of the two sets is the same, i.e., their elements can be identified in such a way that they act the same way?**

Comment: Okay, give your definition of isomorphism on sets. Since usually this notion defined on sets with operation.

Comment: @Jihad Ok, maybe a better question would be why does set equality automatically imply the preservation of the structure, whatever that structure may be?  How do we know set equality implies elements behave in the same way?

Comment: @Jihad I mean my question in the most abstract sense possible.  I don't want to say the set is endowed with $+$ and $\cdot$, for example.  We could have different operations, or maybe just one operation, or who knows what else.  But set equality is simply defined as $A = B$ if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, and this somehow implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There seem to be two problems here.

First, if $A$ and $B$ have the same elements (every element of $A$ is an element of $B$ and vice versa), then they **are the same set**, the strongest possible form of equivalence.

And the identity function (which sends every $x\in A$ to itself) is certainly a bijection $A\to A$ and preserves whichever structure we care to equip $A$ with. So $A$ is always isomorphic to itself.

Second, the word "isomorphic" denotes **many different concepts**, depending on *which* kind of structure we require the isomorphism to preserve. If we say that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic *as sets*, we only require that it's a bijection, and "isomorphic" is then the same as "has the same cardinality".

But we can also speak about being isomorphic as groups, or as rings, or as partially ordered sets, or as graphs, or as a lot of other things. In each of those cases we're strictly speaking using **sloppy language** to speak not only of $A$ and $B$ *in themselves* as sets (that is, which elements they have), but also *additionally* (and implicitly) about some structure we have *chosen* to consider for each of $A$ and $B$. The structure might be a binary operation on the set (when we're speaking of isomorphic-as-groups), or two binary operation (for isomorphic-as-rings), or an order relation (for isomorphic-as-posets), and so forth.

For example, if we say that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as groups, then what we *really* mean is that we have chosen operations $*:A\times A\to A$ and $\circledast:B\times B\to B$ such that $\langle A,{*}\rangle$ and $\langle B,{\circledast}\rangle$ are groups (and having made those choices is neccessary before we can even *ask* whether $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic groups) *and* that there is an $f:A\to B$ that is a bijection and satisfies $f(a_1*a_2)=f(a_1)\circledast f(a_2)$.

What we really should be saying is "the groups $\langle A,{*}\rangle$ and $\langle B,{\circledast}\rangle$ are isomorphic". But we're employing an **informal shorthand** where we can say $A$ when we mean $\langle A,{*}\rangle$, provided that it is clear which ${*}$ we mean.

Note that it is possible for $A$ and $B$ to be the same *set*, yet because we have chosen different $*$ and $\circledast$ they are not isomorphic by structure. For example, $\langle \mathbb R,{+}\rangle$ and $\langle \mathbb R,{\times}\rangle$ are not isomorphic as monoids, even though the underlying set $\mathbb R$ is the same.

Comment: I agree with you completely.  I don't want to impose a structure on the two sets $A$ and $B$ because, I think, in all of these different structures, when $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ (a purely set theoretic statement), it follows that $A$ has the same *structure* as $B$.  How can a purely set theoretic statement imply anything about additional structure on the sets?

Comment: @user46944: Your assumption is not true. Consider the example of $\langle\mathbb R,{+}\rangle$ versus $\langle\mathbb R,{\times}\rangle$. It is certainly the case that $\mathbb R\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\supseteq \mathbb R$, but the two structures are different. Purely set-theoretic containment _cannot_ imply anything about the additional structure -- for the trivial reason that "purely set-theoretic" _means_ that we're ignoring all additional structure.

Comment: I think this is a very important point then.  In all of my years in math, I have only ever heard, regardless of the context, that two sets are equal if they are subsets of each other, and that is what we need to prove.  But clearly that is not the case.  We have to check the structure.  So why don't we?

Comment: @user46944: When we use the word "set", this implies that _there is no additional structure to check_. If you want to speak about a situation where you do check some additional structure, you don't say "set", but instead "group" or "ring" or "poset", or some other word that will tell the listener which structure it is that you're considering.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out.  But if we want to prove two groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are *equal*, not just isomorphic, all I've ever seen that we do is show $G_{1} = G_{2}$, and nothing further.  What about their underlying structure?

Comment: @user46944: In that case the text you've been reading is sloppy. Typically one would consider, for example, equality among subgroups of some group $G=\langle G,{*}\rangle$. Then the group $\langle H,{\circledast}\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H\subseteq G$ _and_ $\circledast$ is the restriction of $*$ to $H\times H$. So whenever $H$ is given there is only one possible $\circledast$ that will make it a subgroup. ...

Comment: ... Thus if we already know that $\langle H_1,{\circledast}\rangle$ and $\langle H_2,{\otimes}\rangle$ are both subgroups of $G$, then just knowing that $H_1=H_2$ _as sets_ also tells us that $\langle H_1,{\circledast}\rangle$ and $\langle H_2,{\otimes}\rangle$ are the same group, because then ${\circledast}$ and $\otimes$ are the same operation because each of them must be the restriction of $*$ to $H_1\times H_1$ (which is the same set as $H_2\times H_2$).

Comment: Your last two comments really got at the heart of my question.  That's exactly what I was asking, and you were able to clear it up.  You even cleared it up with my example in the comment section of Asaf's answer.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Isomorphism means "similar structure", so you have to be more accurate and say what type of structure. If you want to talk about *every* possible structure, then only way two sets are "always isomorphic" is if they are both the empty set (which carries no structure other than empty sets).

Equality as sets, as Henning writes in his excellent answer, means that the sets are in fact equal. But note that when we say that the group $G$ is *equal* to the group $H$ we mean not only that the sets are equal, but also that the operation is equal (as a set of ordered triplets, or so). We can easily define two non-isomorphic group structures on an infinite set.

If you only consider them as unstructured sets, then isomorphism just says that there is a bijection between the two sets; but then you can't say that the elements "act the same way" since there are no actions. Equality means that the two sets are the same set. Note that $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ are both singletons, and are therefore isomorphic as sets (i.e. they have the same cardinality), but they are certainly not equal.

Comment: So saying two sets are equal really depends on the context.  If we have a set $A$ and define an operation $+$ on the set, and we have a set $B$ with operation $\oplus$, then we say, in this context, $A = B$ if a) $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, and b) $A \times A \times A = B \times B \times B$, where $A \times A \times A = \{ (a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}) \mid a_{1} + a_{2} = a_{3} \}$ (and $B^{3}$ is defined in the same way).  Doesn't this get messy to check?  Especially if we have two operations, because it's not immediately obvious what type of cartesian product we are working with..

Comment: No. Saying that two sets are equal means that they are equal as sets. Saying that two **structures** are equal means that their underlying sets, and their interpretations of the symbols relevant to the structure are also equal. Sets are sets.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point.  But if we want to check that two *structures* (such as two groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$) are equal, we usually just show containment in both directions, and don't pay attention to structure...at least this is what I've seen in the past.

Comment: I don't know about "usually". If you want to argue that the structures are the same one, literally, then you show that the identity function is an isomorphism. Or you show that one is a substructure of the other, and vice versa, in which case the operations and whatnot must agree with each other.

Comment: Here is an example: suppose $F$ is a finite field (in which case, let's denote it $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$, where $p^{n}$ is the order of the field).  If I want to show this is equal $\mathbb{Z}_{p}(u)$ for some $u \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$, all I need to do is show $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{p}(u)$, as well as the reverse containment.  Why don't I also need to check the structures are equal?  For some reason, it is already understood that the structures are equal in this given context if the sets are equal, and I don't really know why.

Comment: I should mention in my previous example that I know $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is embedded in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$.

Comment: I don't know how you define $\Bbb Z_p(u)$, I'd think it's the transcendental extension of $\Bbb Z_p$ by $u$. But this surely not the case. Either you define it in such way that $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ is literally a substructure of $\Bbb Z_p(u)$; or that this is an abuse of notation and language. And this abuse is completely normal in mathematics, despite the fact that it can be misleading at first.

Comment: @user46944: In that case it is implicit that the structure on $\mathbb Z_p(u)$ is the one it inherits from $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$, because $\mathbb Z_p(u)$ means the smallest subfield of the field we got $u$ from that contains $\mathbb Z_p$ and $u$. So if we can show that $\mathbb Z_p(u)$ has all the elements of $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$, then by definition the operations on those elements behaves the same as the operations of $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ -- because that's where the operations came from in the first place!

Comment: I define it as the smallest field contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$ that contains $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and $u$.

Comment: Okay, so you define it as a substructure of $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$. So indeed you only have to show equality of sets here, since if $M$ is a **substructure** of $N$, they agree on all the relations and operations (whenever they can agree, of course), so to show equality of $M$ and $N$ *as structures* you just need to show that they have the same underlying sets. But here you already have the additional information needed for this inference.

Comment: Yes, I finally understand it now.  In some contexts, it is OK to just check equality of sets, but I guess it's because in those contexts, the operation is the same.

Comment: "If you only consider them as unstructured sets, then [...] you can't say that the elements "act the same way" since there are no actions."

I strongly disagree. If there are no actions, then for every action the sets act in the same way. I find it important to handle empty concepts (zero, empty model, empty product, etc) well.

Comment: @JozefMikušinec: This is an insistence of looking at this through the wrong lens. Not everything is about groups and actions. Sometimes the context, the language, is not talking about actions. There are no actions. So considering "everything is a group action all the time" is just an odd approach to equality and isomorphism.